# How to implement search in react-admin with ra-data-firestore-client

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-admin

In my project, I'm using react-admin (version ^2.9.3) for backoffice and ra-data-firestore-client (version ^0.1.11) for react-admin firestore provider.

According to the react-admin documentation [adding-search-and-filters-to-the-list](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#adding-search-and-filters-to-the-list), i did exactly the same thing with like the following :

- **EventList.js**

```
    // ... Some imports ...

    const EventFilter = (props) => (
        <Filter {...props}>
            <SearchInput label="Rechercher" source="q" alwaysOn />
        </Filter>
    );
    export const EventList = props => (
      <List title="Tous les événements" filters={<EventFilter />} {...props}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="show">
            <TextField source="title" label="Titre" />
            <TextField source="place" label="Lieu" />
            <EditButton />
        </Datagrid>
      </List>
    );
```

- **App.js**

```
    // ... Some imports ...

    import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard';
    import { EventList } from './views/event/Events';

    const firebaseConfig = {};
    const trackedResources = [{ name: 'events', isPublic: true }];

    const authConfig = {userProfilePath: '/admins/', userAdminProp: 'isAdmin'};

    const messages = {fr: frenchMessages, en: englishMessages};
    const i18nProvider = locale => messages[locale];

    const dataProvider = base64Uploader(RestProvider(firebaseConfig, { trackedResources }));

    const LoginPage = () => <Login backgroundImage={require('./assets/login_image.jpg')} />;

    function App() {
        return (
            <Admin 
                locale="fr" i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
                title="Backoffice"
                dashboard={Dashboard}
                dataProvider={dataProvider} 
                authProvider={AuthProvider(authConfig)}
                loginPage={LoginPage}
            >   
                <Resource name="events" 
                          list={EventList}  
                          options={{ label: 'Evénements' }}  
                          icon={EventIcon} 
                />
            </Admin>     
        );
    }

    export default App;
```

Any search word that I enter, the result is always "No result". I don't understand why ! May be i'm missing something. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore currently [does not support full text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) out of the box. Thus, ra-data-firestore-client library does not support a feature that does not exist.